# Import CSS files in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to migrate my HTML to WordPress template. While I'm doing that, I want to keep my CSS files where they are placed and import them to the code. I found out that I can use `functions.php` file to make it easier.

Below is the code that I added to `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function add_theme_codes() {     
 wp_enqueue_style(‘bootstrap’,get_stylesheet_directory_uri().’/css/bootstrap_grid.css’, ‘all’); 
 wp_enqueue_style( ‘style’, get_stylesheet_directory_uri().’/css/main.css’, ‘all’);
}
add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘add_theme_codes’ );
?>
```

But still my WordPress site is not importing the CSS files.

Comment: please share your header.php file code.

Comment: have you used wp_head() function in header.php

Comment: Yes I added wp_head() before </head> tag

Comment: Check your browsers console log. Are there any errors saying it can't find these files?

Comment: No, my console says nothing. There's just a plugin installed message is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still you have selected the answer I would like to answer on your last desire that you want this to work in a proper way that WordPress do. Please check **wp_footer** is called before **body** tag closed or not. Action Hook **wp_enqueue_scripts** will called in **wp_footer** function. Please try once and let me know the result.

Comment: i added wp_footer between </body> and </html> tag. Will it cause a problem here?

Comment: Please try it by adding before </body> hopefully that will do

Answer (score 2):

You can get css file from below code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',   array('parent-style') );
}
?>
```

Or in Header section before wp_head() add below code

```
<link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/css/bootstrap_grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />      
<link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Can you explain the concept behind the parent-style and child-style? In my case I'm using two separate css files which not depended on each other

Comment: It is related to parent theme, child theme concept, If you are using child then you can call css like above example.

Comment: Huh, no. I am just trying to convert my html project to a WordPress theme. I'm not using any other theme.

Comment: That stuff worked. But I feel like using functions.php is the formal way. Anyway thank you for your valuable time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with add_action and this might work

`<?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_register_style('css-ui',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style('css-ui' ); }`