# Using PHP with Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am currently trying to develop a website for fun just to practice. I have written some PHP code locally on my computer together with some css and html. My question is if anyone is familiar with Wordpress? And if so, am I able to import my php files and css into wordpress and use both code and the tools that wordpress has?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import CSS files in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250456/import-css-files-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes.  The first thing you should do is create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

In it, you will have a `style.css` file in which you can add all your custom CSS.

Also in there will be a `functions.php` file. You can add custom PHP in there.

If you're looking to do something more complicated, then look into [writing a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You can create templates on WordPress.

[How to create a template](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/)

On this template, you can save your PHP.

To add CSS to WordPress you can do that by going to Appearance > Customize > Custom CSS.

The path to your Custom CSS section may be different depending on what theme you use.